# what are all the continuous functions $f(x)$ that is has a domain $x>0$ and $f(ab)=\frac{f(a^2)+f(b^2)}{2}$

Tags: continuity, real-numbers

what are all the continuous functions $f(x)$ that is has a domain $x>0$ and $f(ab)=\frac{f(a^2)+f(b^2)}{2}$.

this question was changed because the answer to the original problem [what are all the continuous functions $f(x)$ that is has a domain $x>1$ and $f(ab)=f(a^2)+f(b^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3989420/what-are-all-the-continuous-functions-fx-that-is-has-a-domain-x1-and-fa?noredirect=1#comment8232812_3989420) was trivial and User$8128$ pointed out

> I think it would slightly more interesting to consider $f(ab) = \frac{f(a^2) +f(b^2)}{2}$ That way, there is a formal similarity to the inequality $ab \le \frac{a^2 + b^2}2$

Comment: $\log (x)$  satisfies this, so you might try to prove that the only non-constant solutions are logs to various bases.

Comment: Quite obviously, $f(x)=c_1+c_2\ln x$.

Comment: The recent edit from $C=2$ to general $C$ is pointless. If $C\ne2$ then $f(a^2)=\tfrac2Cf(a^2)$ so $f$ is identically $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's $\log(x)$ it follows the same structure as logs

$\log(ab)=\log(a^2)/2+\log(b^2)/2$

$\log(a)/2=\log(a^{0.5})$

$\log(a^2)/2=\log(a)$

$\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$

definition

$\log$ is in any base

Comment: But it's not clear why $\log$ is the *only* class of functions which satisfies this relation. Good you bring up the example, though.

Answer (score 1):

Write $g(x):=f(e^x)$ to restate the problem as $g((x+y)/2)=(g(x)+g(y))/2$, with $g$ continuous on $\Bbb R$. Finish with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646324/how-to-show-that-f-is-a-straight-line-if-f-fracxy2-fracfxfy2) question, which proves the suitable $g$ are precisely the linear $g$, in accord with @ProfessorVector's characterization of the suitable $f$.